# Anyone can share an example of listerner pattern with me

Tags: java

I am learning a design pattern called listerner. Anyone can share with me an example of this pattern. I do not need anything related to GUI like JWT, Thanks

Comment: Look at [this post](http://ayp-sd.blogspot.com/2013/01/observer-design-pattern-in-java.html) which describes how to build an implementation of Listener (aka Observer) design pattern using modern Java facilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listener pattern is very close to Observer. Basically you just allow other objects to "listen" to your object. Therefore you need to maintain a list of those listeners, and notify them whenever it's needed.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   public static interface Listener {
      public void onNotify();
   }

   private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

   // addListener and removeListener methods omitted.

   public void doSomething() {
      // do something that listeners should be notified of.

      // notify listeners like this:
      for (Listener l : listeners) {
         l.onNotify();
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Interesting - I'm a Java noob, and have done this with an 'external' interface, and made listener objects implement that interface... I assume some typecasting is done in the addListener method ?  This seems cleaner :)

Comment: No you do not need any kind of typecasting. But you need to fully qualify the name of the interface, which will be MyClass.Listener.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example use of the pattern in Java, since you're not asking for something specific...

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    public MyButton() {
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // omgwtfbbqroflolkthxbai
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The listener pattern is actually not in the Gang of Four [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) of design patterns. However, the listener pattern is just another way to look at the observer pattern. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Java) contains a good example of an observer pattern solution written in Java.